# What was wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

So after crawling the web for related answers and all of them not having providing satisfactory answers,I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28816815/3396197) question here.It has been closed because it was voted opinion biased/Too broad.I would like to counter that argument.I asked what is different about the new development environment.I did not ask SO'ers to pick an option or provide me their opinion.It was a somewhat of question that invited [gotchas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_%28programming%29).I tried hard defending the question but it was still closed without an valid explanation.So I was hoping that I would be provided with a valid explanation in meta for the same.

Comment: If someone would atleast tell me what is wrong with the question(specifically) and not "too opinion based",I would try to edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"what should I keep in mind" is an instant red flag (a metaphorical flag, that is) for too broad and/or opinion-based. Stack Overflow works best with specific problems that have specific answers that solve the problem; questions of this nature instead can have any number of answers, none of which can ever fully solve the problem.

Comment: So if i were to say "List the gotchas",Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: @Droidekas This is on the right track, but "gotcha" is vague, and the list would likely be too long. The only comprehensive answer would be a link to the changelog between ART and Dalvik.

Comment: Ok shall edit the question accordingly.

Comment: So rewording my question found me a solution elsewhere.I guess I can just delete the question now.